Можно ли в Qt Designer в окне option сделать перенос строки?
Можно ли в Qt Designer в окне option сделать перенос строки?
Делаю приложение для тестов, вариант ответа бывает довольно большой и не влезает в экран, тогда вся разметка экрана (кнопки, текст вопроса и остальные варианты вопроса) подстраиваются под самый длинный вариант и выходят за пределы экрана.
Можно ли как-то этого избежать? 
Вопрос и варианты ответа берутся из json файла. Свойством wordwap option не обладает.

lalalapaxen, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему
